# Blob and Ajax issue TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, blob

Hi I'm trying to pass a blob in data inside $.ajax

```
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
```

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "myurl",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'test': true,
                'jsonFile': jsonFile,
                'htmlFile': blob,
            },
            success: function(response) {     
                $('#msg').addClass('success');
            }
        });
```

return this error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation

If i delete 'htmlFile': blob, works fine but i must pass a blob.

I read other thread  i tried to use :

- processData: false, contentType: false, -> the error disappears but the variables in post are empty
- var formdata = new FormData() to format in exact way the data but don't work

Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 1):

Adding processData: false should resolve the issue, as this instruction stops jQuery from stringifying the data.